# How to pass the useReducer State to the child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a simple feedback application that contains multiple component.
app.js - parent component

data.js - this contain a dummy data the have name and the listofreview

component

- user - this component will display the name and the thumbnail
- review - this will display the list of review about the user and also have button that say leave a review.

  - modal - after the user click the leave a review this modal will appear that have a list of element that will update the list of review

I used useReducer to update the state. But the problem is the review.js don't show the updated state. maybe because the useReducer is located on the modal.js. What should i do so that i can also update the data that been display on the review.js

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="main-container">
      <DisplayUser />
      <div className="mainContent-container">
        <DisplayReview />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**User.js**

```
import { data } from '../../src/data';

const CommentHandler = () => {
    const [user] = React.useState(data);
    return (
        <>
            {user.map((person) => {
                const { id, name, thumbnail } = person;

                return (
                    <div key={id} className='user-container'>
                        <h2 className="user-name">{name}</h2>
                        <img src={thumbnail} alt={name} title={name} className='user-icon' />
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </>
    );
};
```

**Review.js**

```
import DisplayModal from './Modal'
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { data } from '../../src/data';

const ReviewHandler = () => {
    const [user] = useState(data);
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

    return (
        <>
            {user.map((person) => {
                const { listOfReview } = person;
                return (
                    <div key={person.id} className='review-container active'>
                        <div className="content-container">
                            {listOfReview.map((sub) => {
                                const { reviewId, rating, name, occupation, review } = sub;
                                return (
                                    <div key={reviewId} className="content-container">
                                        <div className='reviewer-rating'>
                                            <div className="static-review">
                                                {[...Array(5)].map((star, index) => {
                                                    return <FontAwesomeIcon key={index} className="star" icon="star" />
                                                })}
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="dynamic-review">
                                                {[...Array(rating)].map((star, index) => {
                                                    return <FontAwesomeIcon key={index} className="star" icon="star" />
                                                })}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="user-description">
                                            <h3>{occupation}</h3>
                                            <h4>{name}</h4>
                                            <p>{review}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                )
                            })}
                            <button className="submit" onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}>LEAVE AREVIEW</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
            <Modal isOpen={showModal} ariaHideApp={false}>
                <DisplayModal onClick={(value) => setShowModal(value)} />
            </Modal>
        </>
    );
};
```

**Modal.js**

```
import { useState, useReducer } from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { data } from '../../src/data';
import { reducer } from './reducer';

const ModalHandler = props => {
    const [rating, setRating] = useState(null);
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [occupation, setOccupation] = useState('');
    const [reviews, setReviews] = useState('');
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, data);
    const [hoverRating, setHoverRating] = useState(null);

    const handelSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (name && occupation && reviews) {
            const newReview = { reviewId: new Date().getTime(), name, occupation, rating, reviews };
            dispatch({
                type: 'ADD_REVIEW_ITEM',
                payload: newReview
            });
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="modal-container">
            <div className="modal-backdrop">
                <form className="modal-inner" onSubmit={handelSubmit}>
                    <h2>Feel feel to send us your review!</h2>
                    <div className='revieweRating-container'>
                        <h3>How was your experience?</h3><p onClick={() => props.onClick(false)}>X</p>
                        <div className="dynamic-review">
                            {[...Array(5)].map((star, i) => {
                                const ratingValue = i + 1;
                                return (
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="radio"
                                            name="review-star"
                                            value={ratingValue}
                                            onMouseEnter={() => setHoverRating(ratingValue)}
                                            onMouseLeave={() => setHoverRating(ratingValue)}
                                            onClick={() => setRating(ratingValue)}>
                                        </input>
                                        <FontAwesomeIcon
                                            icon="star"
                                            onMouseEnter={() => setHoverRating(ratingValue)}
                                            onMouseLeave={() => setHoverRating(ratingValue)}
                                            color={ratingValue <= (hoverRating || rating) ? "#FAD020" : "#BCC5D3"}
                                            className="review-star" />
                                    </label>
                                )
                            })}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="name"
                        className="name"
                        placeholder="Name"
                        value={name}
                        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="occupation"
                        className="alioccupationas"
                        placeholder="Aloccupationias"
                        value={occupation}
                        onChange={(e) => setOccupation(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <textarea
                        name="review"
                        cols="30"
                        rows="6"
                        className="review"
                        placeholder="Enter your review here!"
                        value={reviews}
                        onChange={(e) => setReviews(e.target.value)}>
                    </textarea>
                    <button type="submit" className="submit">SEND A REVIEW</button>
                </form>
                <div>
                    {state.map((data) => (
                        <div key={data.id}>
                            {data.listOfReview.map((review) => (
                                <div key={review.reviewId}>
                                    <h3>{review.name}</h3>
                                    <p>{review.occupation}</p>
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div >
    );
}
```

**reducer.js**

```
export const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "ADD_REVIEW_ITEM":
            console.log(state);
            return state.map((data) => {
                if (data) {
                    const newReview = [...data.listOfReview, action.payload];

                    return {
                        ...data,
                        listOfReview: newReview
                    };
                }
                return data;
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

**data.js**

```
export const data = [
    {
        id: 1607089645363,
        name: 'Andress Bonifacio',
        noOfReview: 1,
        listOfReview: [
            {
                reviewId: 1607089645361,
                name: 'Juan Dela Cruz',
                occupation: 'Father of Phil. Revolution',
                rating: 5,
                review: 'Numquam labore or dolorem enim but accusantium and autem ratione.',
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: It's hard to be able to help without seeing some code, could you post the components which use the reducer, as well as the definition of the reducer itself, and any other code you think may be relevant?

Comment: Sure, i already update the code above. the useReducer is located on the modal.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the updated `data` across all component, then make sure to have this line of code `const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, data);` available in every `component` that **use** them like in:-

#### in `User.js`

```js
import { data } from '../../src/data';
import { reducer } from './reducer';

const CommentHandler = () => {
    // not this
    const [user] = React.useState(data);
    // instead this
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, data);
    
    return (
        <>
            {state.map((person) => {
                const { id, name, thumbnail } = person;

                return (
                    <div key={id} className='user-container'>
                        <h2 className="user-name">{name}</h2>
                        <img src={thumbnail} alt={name} title={name} className='user-icon' />
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </>
    );
};
```

#### in `Review.js`

```js
import { useState, useReducer } from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { data } from '../../src/data';
import { reducer } from './reducer';

const ReviewHandler = () => {
    // not this
    // const [user] = useState(data);
    // instead this
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, data);
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

    return (
        <>
            {state.map((person) => {
                const { listOfReview } = person;
                return (
                    <div key={person.id} className='review-container active'>
                        <div className="content-container">
                            {listOfReview.map((sub) => {
                                const { reviewId, rating, name, occupation, review } = sub;
                                return (
                                    <div key={reviewId} className="content-container">
                                        <div className='reviewer-rating'>
                                            <div className="static-review">
                                                {[...Array(5)].map((star, index) => {
                                                    return <FontAwesomeIcon key={index} className="star" icon="star" />
                                                })}
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="dynamic-review">
                                                {[...Array(rating)].map((star, index) => {
                                                    return <FontAwesomeIcon key={index} className="star" icon="star" />
                                                })}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="user-description">
                                            <h3>{occupation}</h3>
                                            <h4>{name}</h4>
                                            <p>{review}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                )
                            })}
                            <button className="submit" onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}>LEAVE AREVIEW</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
            <Modal isOpen={showModal} ariaHideApp={false}>
                <DisplayModal onClick={(value) => setShowModal(value)} />
            </Modal>
        </>
    );
};
```

I would suggest you try and use `context api` instead of just relying on `useReducer`.

Comment: You may refer to this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-context-apireviews-08eel?file=/src/App.js) if you're looking forward to change your application to use `Context API`